# Conflict between titlesec and minitoc

Tags: minitoc

I try to create a minitoc inside of my document.
First the minitoc don't appear, and second I get this message:

> Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0099(minitoc(hints))
>   --- The titlesec package is loaded. (minitoc(hints))                It is incompatible (minitoc(hints))                with the minitoc
>   package.

Is it because of him that my minitoc is not printed?
If you want the full document (approximatively 10MB) I can share it to see in detail.

The log of output are here :https://pastebin.com/hC9JLZzJ

Comment: See if you can create a MINIMAL file which displays the same error message.  Or take your existing file throw out everything that does not involve the toc.

Comment: See pages 53-54 of the minitoc manual.